# First/Last record is not coming with data in cakephp+mongo

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

I m using the mongodb plugin 
[ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb)

And cakephp 2.6.1

The data in post collection
[image]
[link to image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/10557703/6037521/6bcd3552-ac7a-11e4-8737-9149803f9a1a.png)

And in cakephp it is showing me like
[image]
[link to image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/10557703/6037522/6c06ae72-ac7a-11e4-9f36-11f0d924059c.png)

Cakephp controller side code:

```
$params = array(
            'fields' => array('title', 'body', 'hoge'),
            //'fields' => array('Post.title', ),
            //'conditions' => array('title' => 'hehe'),
            //'conditions' => array('hoge' => array('$gt' => '10', '$lt' => '34')),
            //'order' => array('title' => 1, 'body' => 1),
             'order' => array('_id' => "DESC"),
             'limit' => 35,
             'page' => 1,
        );
        $results = $this->Post->find('all', $params);
```

I want to pull each and every data from mongodb but this plugin is not providing me the last data.
I have checked the count that's correct.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear what you are trying to do, and what is not working as intended. Please try not to link to external sources. Then your question would get more attention.

Comment: What you tried so far? Where is cakephp code?

Comment: @BatScream,Thanks for suggestions.I'll do it.
I have link to external sources because its not allowing me to attach image.

Comment: @Sadikhasan,I have put the code and also updated the image for better understanding.

Comment: @Sadikhasan,   Sorry,Still not working :(

Comment: It's working fine for me I checked it.

Comment: Check in your database may be it `blank` entry, your code is fine.

Comment: @Sadikhasan,please review the first image.

Comment: `debug($results);` OR `print_r($result);` and what it prints and let me know.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Post] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => 54d0f4d9299a652bb6b7acd9
                    [title] => 3
                    [body] => 3
                    [hoge] => 3
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Post] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => 54d0eb83299a659c78b7acd9
                    [title] => vivek
                    [body] => doshi
                    [hoge] => vivek doshi
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Post] => 
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in assuming that this error only appeared after upgrading the PHP driver to 1.6.0? The CakePHP module uses [`hasNext()` and `getNext()`](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/blob/9a97fbc1a9d08291319a43eb9b243ce7e4acb07c/Model/Datasource/MongodbSource.php#L1168) in `MongodbSource::read()`, which will be affected by a bug ([PHP-1382](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-1382)) introduced in 1.6.0. A fix has already been merged and should be released as 1.6.1 on 2015-02-05 (tomorrow).

For additional context, see a previous answer on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28304142/162228

Comment: The 1.6.1 driver is now available, which should fix the problem you were experiencing: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases/tag/1.6.1

Comment: FYI: 1.6.1 missed an edge case with `hasNext()`. This should be fixed in 1.6.2, which was released today: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases/tag/1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

In MongodbSource.php file I have made just simple change
in read function

There was a code

```
public function read(Model $Model, $query = array(), $recursive = null) {
........
while ($return->hasNext()) {
                $mongodata = $return->getNext();
```

Changed it to

```
public function read(Model $Model, $query = array(), $recursive = null) {
    ........
foreach ($return as $data) {
                $mongodata = $data;
```

And yurekaaaa,its working fine.